# Is there a term for common constructions like "X in general, and Y in particular?"

Tags: terminology, figure-of-speech

I have seen a syntactic meme that isn't common where I grew up. It is "X in general, and Y in particular" where Y has a meronym/part-to-whole relation with X. Here are some examples I found by searching Linguee.com:

- "**Other harmful traditional practices in general, and the practice of early marriage in particular**, are also being systematically addressed."
- "Although patriarchy, machismo and excessive masculine displays are assumed to be prevalent among **Latinos in general and Mexicans in particular**, little is known. . ."
- " [...] the focus is on **developing countries in general and on the least developed countries in particular**, which are recognized by the United Nations [...] "

Speakers could say "Generally X, and specifically Y," for example, which would mean the same thing, but they don't. The "X in general, and Y in particular" construction is kind of a meme.

Is there a term for this kind of expression? "Turn of phrase," trope, and figure of speech all seem wrong because they refer to more literal constructions that don't allow filling in the blank with a lexical category like this one.

Comment: I'd call it a template.

Comment: [Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_grammar#Concepts)?

Comment: Yes, I'd call it a **Construction**, like the _let alone_ construction in [Fillmore, Kay, and O'Connor 1988](https://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/~filip/fillmore+88.pdf).